# Parse Mutable Live Data to Array in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, nsmutabledata

There is a mutableLiveData Holding 2 array "deal" and "category" I need to parse this both in different adapters.

Is there a way I can convert 1 mutable live data to 2 array and then parse them to two different adapters

Suppose There is MutableVariable Name se

`private lateinit var mHomePojo: MutableLiveData<List<HomePojo>>`

having parse Json as below

```
 {
   "status": 0,
   "response": "success",
   "category": [
     {
       "categoryName": "demo",
       "categoryDesc": "demo"
     },
     {
       "categoryName": "demo1",
       "categoryDesc": "demo"
     }
   ],
   "deal": [
     {
       "dealImg": "https://aiotechnology.in/Aditechweb/upload/153102117.jpg",
       "dealDesc": "gd",
       "dealStartDate": "2019-10-18",
       "dealEndDate": "2019-10-19"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Is there any way to parse `private lateinit var mHomePojo: MutableLiveData<List<HomePojo>>` to `lateinit var mDealModel: MutableLiveData<List<DealModel>>` and 
    `lateinit var mCategoryModel: MutableLiveData<List<CategoryModel>>`

I am new to MVVM please help

Comment: Have you tried anything? hint : `.map{}` is used when you need typeA to typeB transformation

Comment: No I did not try .map{} I will look into it

Comment: @NewUser are you sure it will help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Transformations might be able to help you separate your home live data to two separate livedata object with specified properties. below is piece of code for this. (NOTE : not used lateinit var for example)

```
private val homeLiveData: LiveData<HomePojo> = MutableLiveData<HomePojo>()

//Category Live data
private val categoryPojo = Transformations.map(homeLiveData) {
    it.category
}

//Deal live data
private val dealPojo = Transformations.map(homeLiveData) {
    it.deal
}

data class HomePojo(
   /*-- Other fields --*/
   val category: List<CategoryPojo>? = null,
   val deal: List<DealPojo>? = null)


data class CategoryPojo(
    val categoryName: String? = null,
    val categoryDesc: String? = null)

data class DealPojo(
    val dealImg: String? = null,
    val dealDesc: String? = null,
    val dealStartDate: String? = null,
    val dealEndDate: String? = null)
```

Comment: can you please help me is below is right way to parse live data in adapter
homeFragmentDealAdapter = HomeFragmentDealAdapter(this,
            mHomeFragmentViewModel.mDealModel.value as ArrayList<DealModel>
        )

Comment: becz I am getting error "kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: not implemented"

Comment: is it possible for you to show me your initialisation code for mDealModel and HomeFragmentDealAdapter?